# Why is the pipe not working?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I am stumped as to why a pipe doesn't work.

```
/(?:<img.*?src=[\'"](.*?)[\'"].*?>)|(http(?:[^\s]*)\.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png))/
```

Here is the full pastebin of the code: http://pastebin.com/J2y8jbsg

For example a link such as:

```
http://guardianlv.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Robots-The-Possibilities-of-Artificial-Intelligence.jpg
```

will be captured if the second regex pattern is alone. `(http(?:[^\s]*)\.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png))`

But when I add it with another, as shown initially above and in the pastebin, as a pipe, all I get is an empty array:

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => )
```

Can someone explain this? And also a solution would be helpful :) Thank you.

Comment: Oh, damn silly me lol. Please provide an answer and you get it. Thank you very much. Have a good night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first part:

```
<img.*?src=[\'"](.*?)[\'"].*?>
                 ^
```

this is the first capture group. So:

```
(http(?:[^\s]*)\.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png)
```

is your second capture group. So:

```
foreach ( $matches[1] as $url ) {
```

is incorrect. You can use:

```
foreach ( $matches[2] as $url ) {
```

or

```
foreach ( $matches[0] as $url ) {
```

for the full match.

Demo: https://eval.in/705305

Regex101 demo: https://regex101.com/r/KXjmo3/1

Comment: Thanks. I don't know if it was you that commented first. Thanks again. Rooky mistake on my part.

Comment: @KrNel yea, I commented then deleted. Was providing functional examples so you can see the actual issue.